# Is it possible to copy CommCare reports from one project space to another?

Tags: commcare

I have two project spaces that have similarly-structured applications. I would like to copy the reports from my old project space over to my new project space so that I can adapt them for use in my new project.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there currently doesn't exist functionality to easily copy Report Builder reports from one project space to another.

If you have access to the UCR configuration of the reports, you can copy the json configuration and paste that configuration into the new reports. There might be a few changes you would have to make to the json in order for it to fully work depending on a few things.

Comment: You would have to copy the json config for the data source + the reports configuration. However if there was a custom expression created for the reports, you would need a separate PR for the new project space.